# What happens if edit maven settings.xml mirrors while a maven project is building and downloading?

Tags: maven

What happens if one were to edit maven `$MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml` (alt. `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`) mirrors while a maven project is building and downloading? Would this mess with anything (or does, for example, a "snapshot" of certain settings get taken and used when running a `mvn` command)?

Comment: You're basically asking if the file is loaded repeatedly during the process?

Comment: @DaveNewton I guess so, lol. When you put it that way a likely answer seems more apparent.

Comment: You got my meaning then ;) That said--there are mechanisms that would lend itself to such abuse, and while I don't actually know, it seems unlikely.

Comment: If I correctly remember the code the `settings.xml` from global `conf/settings.xml` and `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` are loaded at the very beginning of the build (can be checked `mvn clean verify -X | grep "Reading "`) and not loaded again ..so it should be a problem..apart from really academic....